# Filling a shape with other small shapes in HTML,CSS,JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[image: Filling a shape with other small shapes]

I want to fill in a shape dynamically with random sized & random number of balls using html, css, & jQuery.

For example in the figure attached, "Figure A" is the custom shape I want to fill in when a user add a ball (Ball will actually be user pictures when he puts a comment). For example 100 users put their comment, I want to put 100 balls of random size, color in the shape of "Figure A". Figure A is currently showing a line but when I am filling it with these circles, the line won't be visible, so the shape would become from the circles.

Any idea how to achieve that ? or Any example someone has already done that before in HTML, CSS, jQuery ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it acceptable that the circles overlap?

Comment: @fiddler Thanks for you prompt comment.  Overlapping circles, no actually. I want them to have a small margin around the circles, say 2px;

Comment: What you want to achieve is hard. It would be better you already have something and you're stuck at some point. An "easiest" solution would be to already place an array of points and create an overlaps algorithm which will say - *If my place was took by the biggest circle, exclude my nearest points from the "Available points" array to prevent any smaller circle overlap me"*. Also Google for *Detect circle collision*.

Comment: How many days of work are you willing to spend on this?

Comment: @ThomasW 3 to 4 days I guess, or may be a week.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I would approach the problem:

1. Map out the circles eg hard code the layout and keep them hidden until they have been populated. The cicles would basically be place holders with unique ids.
2. If the cirles are created dynamically, use box2dweb which is a physics engine with collision detection built in. Its taking a sledge hammer to crack a nut, but it would allow you to extend you project with some arresting animation and user interaction. The circles could be draggable and the user could move their picture around etc. You can set the gravity yourself so they can fall or float up into the containing shape you construct. Seth Ladd has a comprehensive set of tutorials online. You will need a good understanding of html canvas too.